# Does `inquestion` support multiple question ids?

Tags: support, questions

The `q` parameter has an `inquestion` operator that can take a question id.

Can it take *multiple* question ids?

My use-case is as follows:

- I want to get an array of questions with their excerpts.
- However, `search/excerpts` results *don't include many of `/questions` properties* (e.g., `owner`, `view_count`, bounty-related props, etc.), hence I'm forced to make **>1** calls to get all desired properties.
- If `inquestion` doesn't support multiple ids, I need to make **1 + n** calls (1 to  `/questions`, and n to `search/exceprts`, where n is the number of returned questions). But if it does, I would only need to make **2** calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. It's the same operator as in the [regular site search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and that does not support multiple IDs either.

However, if you need the excerpt from a list of questions you already know the ID of, you can consider retrieving the `body` with the `/questions` call (by applying the correct [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters)) and stripping the HTML elements. That's pretty close to what the excerpt does.

Comment: For future reference: I ended up actually using `body_markdown`, [replacing multiple space characters with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1981366/3002584), then [decoded HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915311/3002584), and finally [made an excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40382963/3002584) out of the stripped string.