# Formatting and formatted content is missing for body in search excerpts call

Tags: bug, search, api-v2.3

The `body` returned by the [search excerpts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) call seems to omit formatting and sometimes even formatted content. Example calls follow for this question: [Does `inquestion` support multiple question ids?](https://stackapps.com/q/9174/34061)

- The [search excerpts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=inquestion%3A9174&filter=default&site=stackapps&run=true) call returns `"body": "The  parameter has an  operator that can take a question id.\nCan it take multiple question ids?\nMy use-case is as follows:\n\nI want to get an array of questions with their excerpts.\n\nHowever,  results don&#39;t include many of  properties...`
- Post information calls like [questions by IDs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=9174&filter=!nKzQUR3Egv&site=stackapps&run=true) return `"body": "<p>The <code>q</code> parameter has an <code>inquestion</code> operator that can take a question id.</p>\n<p>Can it take <em>multiple</em> question ids?</p>\n<p>My use-case is as follows:</p>\n<ul>\n<li><p>I want to get an array of questions with their excerpts.</p>\n</li>\n<li><p>However, <code>search/excerpts</code> results <em>don't include many of <code>/questions</code> properties</em>...`

It's logical that the formatting is stripped for the `excerpt` return field, but that is an intelligent stripping which leaves the content alone: `"excerpt": "The q parameter has an inquestion operator that can take a question id.\nCan it take multiple question ids?\nMy use-case is as follows:\n\nI want to get an array of questions with their excerpts.\n\nHowever &hellip; "`. The current `body` field is rather useless, since e.g. the `<code>q</code>` is omitted entirely, instead of being replaced with `q`. Note that `<em>multiple</em>` has been replaced with `multiple` so in that case the content is preserved.